# What's the name of this suspense/sci fi TV show from the late 70's early 80's?

Tags: soft-sci-fi, story-identification

I remember watching a show in the late 70's or early 80's that I would like to see again. Each episode had 3 on-going stories. So each episode adds a little to each story. The episodes don't stand on their own. The first story was a wild west story: mid to late 19th century, small town, gunfighters, etc. This was no ordinary wild west story as there were aliens. I think I remember 1 episode where they showed a spaceship. That's all I can remember about that story.  The second story was about a female investigative reporter. She finds out something really big is going to happen. She doesn't know what but it's big like a terrorist attack or assassination or something. The whole story is her following clues trying to figure out what this big event is. I thought it might have been Susan Anton but I don't recognize the names of her shows in the 70's and 80's on IMDB so I don't know if it was her. I don't remember anything about the 3rd story. I saw maybe 5-10 episodes and then I don't know what happened. It might have been canceled. That's not much to go on but that's all I can remember. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Any other clues? What language was it in? What country did you watch it in? It sounds like an American show, but that can't be assumed on this site.

Comment: I watched it in Canada in English. It would definitely have been American.

Answer (score 12):

I am pretty sure you are talking about [Cliffhangers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cliffhangers_%28TV_series%29)

> ...three serials were featured - a mystery, a science fiction/western hybrid, and a horror story:
>
> "Stop Susan Williams": Susan Anton stars as a beautiful TV journalist investigating the murder of her brother, and stumbling on a vast international conspiracy.
>
> "The Secret Empire": the adventures of a U.S. marshal (Geoffrey Scott) in the Old West who stumbles upon a futuristic underground city run by aliens.
>
> "The Curse of Dracula": starring Michael Nouri as Count Dracula, who is living undercover as a college teacher in 1979 San Francisco.

Comment: What about Cliffhangers matches the description?

Comment: Wow! Brandon, I think you nailed it. That was impressive. Looks like I was right about Susan Anton but wrong about a couple of other facts. I even recognize the title. Thanks.

Comment: phantom42, I think I was wrong about the spaceship but other than that what I wrote seems very similar to the description Brandon found and posted above. I'm pretty sure the show is Cliffhangers.

Comment: @Locutus: When you come back, please click on the green checkmark to accept if you think it is the right answer.

Answer (score -1):

I do not remember the 3 on-going stories feature, but your description resembles Outlaws...

[Outlaws](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090498/)

Comment: Outlaws looks like just 1 story so that can't be it. Thanks.